# Searching within my own application

Tags: android, search

So im building an Android application and want to include a search feature to let users use it instead of having to look through the apps many activities and pages. Cant seem to find any info on the best way to do this anywhere else. Thanks in advance

Ok so im building an app that will serve as a game guide for a popular PS3 game. Within the app will be many subjects and topics and i would like to give users the ooption to just use a search bar on the main screen of the app to search throughout the entire application and then provide them with a list of results that are clickable and take them directly to the chosen activity or place in the application. (Say it was an app for making whiskey, i would want them to be able to search on the main page for Jack Daniels instead of hitting buttons that navigate from Mainpage>American Whiskey's>Bourbon>Jack Daniels. )

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Not clear on what you are looking for. Provide more details (or) code.

Comment: OP updated. Thanks again